# Julia (JuMP): Indicator constraints with multiple conditional values (is a boolean expression possible?)

Tags: boolean, julia, julia-jump

I want to implement a constraint depending on the change of values in my binary decision variable, `x`, over "time".

I am trying to implement a minimum operating time constraint for a unit commitment optimization problem for power systems. `x` is representing the unit activation where `0` and `1` show that a power unit, `n`, at a certain time, `t`, respectively is shut off or turned on.

For this, [indicator constraints](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/constraints/#Indicator-constraints-1) seem to be a promising solution and with the inspiration of a [similar problem](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jump-conditional-constraint/40575/6) the implementation seemed quite straightforward.

So, since boolean operators are introduced (`!` and `¬`), I prematurely wanted to express the change in a boolean way:

```
@constraint(m, xx1[n=1:N,t=2:T], (!x[n,t-1] && x[n,t]) => {next(t, 1) + next(t, 2) == 2})
```

Saying: if unit was deactivated before but now is on, then demand the unit to be active for the next 2 times.

Where `next(t, i) = x[((t - 1 + i) % T) + 1]`.

I got the following error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching !(::VariableRef)
Closest candidates are:
  !(!Matched::Missing) at missing.jl:100
  !(!Matched::Bool) at bool.jl:33
  !(!Matched::Function) at operators.jl:896
```

I checked that the indicator constraint is working properly with a single term only.

**Question:** Is this possible or is there another obvious solution?

**Troubleshooting and workarounds:** I have tried the following (please correct me if my diagnosis is wrong):

- Implement change as an expression: indicator constraints only work with binary integer variables.
- Implement change as another variable relating to `x`. I have found a solution but it is quite sketchy, which is documented in a [Julia discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/constraining-binary-integer-variables-with-indicator-constraints/51043). The immediate problem, found from the solution, is that indicator constraints do not work as bi-implication but only one way, `LHS->RHS`. **Please see the [proper approach](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/constraining-binary-integer-variables-with-indicator-constraints/51043/9) given by @Oscar Dowson**.

You can get the working code from [github](https://github.com/bvilmann/jl_test_scripts/blob/main/boolean_indicator_constraint.jl).

Comment: Please add a link if you cross-post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/constraining-binary-integer-variables-with-indicator-constraints/51043

Comment: Noted! Thanks very much for your persistent support on both sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to find constraint(s) that have an equivalent truth-table:

```
# Like
(!x[1] && x[2]) => {z == 1}

# Is equivalent to:
z >= -x[1] + x[2]

# Proof
-x[1] + x[2] = sum <= z
--------------------------
 - 0  +  0   =  0  <= 0
 - 1  +  0   =  -1 <= 0 
 - 0  +  1   =  1  <= 1
 - 1  +  1   =  0  <= 0
```

I was recommended [MOSEK Modeling Cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html) to help working out the correct formulation of constraints.

See eventually the thread [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/constraining-binary-integer-variables-with-indicator-constraints/51043/9) from where I got the answer for further details.

Comment: The third row in the `sum` column should read `1`.